# How to add relative img path on render in Nuxtjs from markdown?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuejs3

I'm using nuxt-responsive-loader to have srcset images,
When i use

```
 <img class="card-img-top" :srcset="require('~/assets/nuxt2.png').srcSet"  alt="Sample image" />
```

it renders img in in srcset , but when i try to load via my markdown file dyanmically  it doesn't,

```
<img class="card-img-top" :srcset="require(article.img).srcSet"  alt="Sample image" />
```

and give's error, **can't **find module ~/assets/nuxt2.png.****

Note: I'm using asyncData

```
<script>
export default {
  async asyncData({ $content, params }) {
    const article = await $content('articles', params.slug).fetch()
    console.log(params)
    const [prev, next] = await $content('articles')
      .only(['title', 'slug'])
      .sortBy('createdAt', 'asc')
      .surround(params.slug)
      .fetch()
    return { article, prev, next }
}
</script>
```

**My-First-blog.md**

```
title: How i started my developing career
description: 'This is a roadmap of todo list while starting with software developer in it field and excelling it.'
author: jerryyhank
img: ~/assets/nuxt2.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "require" and syntax like this

```
<img class="card-img-top" :srcset="require('~/assets/'+article.img).srcSet" alt="Sample i/>
```

In the My-First-blog.md , just add te img name

```
title: How i started my developing career
description: 'This is a roadmap of todo list while starting with software developer in it field and excelling it.'
author: jerryyhank
img: nuxt2.png
```